# Chain/Node shaped bash prompt

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

After going through some UTF-8 character list I was unable to make my prompt like a chain/node....( See the [figure](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ku5hnapxmsd6170/bp.png?dl=0) )
. I'm in Ubuntu using gnome-terminal, that supports UTF-8. Is that prompt style specific to iTerm or It can be achieved in any terminal emulator? I was hoping to get a bash prompt like the one in this [figure](https://www.dropbox.com/s/39d8njjjiuwgcjy/chain.png?dl=0)......
any ideas

Comment: Those are both the exact same image...

Comment: anything you did try yourself?

Comment: @JNYRanger Sorry pasted wrong one

Comment: @planetmaker Ya I did checkout the first figure, It turned out to be really sucky

Comment: both figures show some kind of prompt... but I don't see in either any attempt of yours to configure anything (i.e. any configuration you tried in your .bashrc or whatever)

Comment: Ya I tried configuring bashrc by inserting some new UTF-8 characters
First one is mine and second is the one I got inspired of

Comment: Show us your current `PS1` value and tell us **exactly** what you are still missing from your attempt that you cannot figure out how to get to work.

Comment: PS1='\[\033[01;37m\]└──[\[\033[00m\]\[\033[01;31m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\[\033[01;37m\]]──[\[\033[00m\]\[\033[01;34m\]ѱ \[\033[00m\]$(gitp)\[\033[01;37m\]]\n   \[\033[01;37m\]└──>\[\033[00m\] '

This is not that good at all. I need the prompt to be exactly same as the second figure

Comment: Using escape characters depends on the terminal or terminal emulator in use.  So different users might see different images.  Is that OK?

Comment: So can you say which terminal for linux for good character rendering?